# InvalidOperationException: The expression is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.1
- .NET Framework Version 4.8.04084
- ASP.NET Core 5, Razor Pages (Not MVC)
- Entity Framework 5

I get an "Invalid Operation" exception in the following code, and I'm not sure why.

In a nutshell, I have two models:

1. Acronym
2. AcronymOld

`Acronym` has a one to many relationship with `AcronymOld`.

Acronym:

```
public class Acronym
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Acronym")]
     [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Acronym cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
     public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Description")]
     [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
     public string Description { get; set; }

     [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "URL cannot be longer than 250 characters.")]
     public string URL { get; set; }

     public List<AcronymOld> AcronymsOld { get; set; }
}
```

AcronymOld:

```
public class AcronymOld
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Previous Acronym")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Previous Acronym cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Previous Acronym Description")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Previous Acronym Description cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Used")]
    public DateTime LastUsed { get; set; }

    //Acronym Can Have One or More AcronymOld
    [ForeignKey("AcronymId")]
    public int AcronymId { get; set; }
    public Acronym Acronym { get; set; }
}
```

Code in question:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool isDirty = false;

    public List<SelectListItem> Acronyms { get; set; }
    public IList<AcronymOld> AcronymOld { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string SelectedAcronym { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        // Populate Acronym SelectList
        Acronyms = _context.Acronym.Select(a =>
                              new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                                  Text = a.Abbreviation,
                              }).ToList();

        var acronymsOld = from m in _context.AcronymOld
                          select m;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedAcronym))
        {
            acronymsOld = acronymsOld.Where(m => m.Id == Int32.Parse(SelectedAcronym));
            isDirty = true;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            if (isDirty == true)
            {
                // AcronymOld selected. Do not GroupBy
                acronymsOld = acronymsOld.Where(m => m.Abbreviation.Contains(SearchString));
            }
            else
            {
                //AcronymOld not selected. Use GroupBy
                acronymsOld = acronymsOld.Where(m => m.Abbreviation.Contains(SearchString));
            }
        }

        AcronymOld = await acronymsOld.Include(m => m.AcronymId)
            .OrderBy(m => m.Abbreviation)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error here on this line:

```
AcronymOld = await acronymsOld.Include(m => m.AcronymId)
            .OrderBy(m => m.Abbreviation)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
```

Detailed error:

> InvalidOperationException: The expression 'm.AcronymId' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigation declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending)
>
> AcronymOld = await acronymsOld.Include(m => m.AcronymId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **navigation property** (`m.Acronym` - not the `AcronymId` value) in your `.Include()` - try this:

```
AcronymOld = await acronymsOld.Include(m => m.Acronym)
                              .OrderBy(m => m.Abbreviation)
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .ToListAsync();
```